# retrieving text/chat messages?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Can I programmatically retrieve certain user's messages/chats from the messaging application of the WP7 OS ?

I wan either to be able to retrieve certain user's or all of the messages through my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this would be too much of a potential for some really bad apps.